# Python - ms_active_directory - Is it possible to get a crypt password from a user

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, active-directory, cryptography

I connected my Flask application with an Active Directory Server using ms_active_directory library. Is it possible to get a crypt password from a user? Something like this:

```
import os
from ms_active_directory import ADDomain

domain = ADDomain(os.environ["domain"])
session = domain.create_session_as_user(os.environ["userAd"], os.environ["passAd"])
user = session.find_user_by_sam_name('John Liniker', ["userPassword"])
```

I would like to get this password, type a new one, use the same crypt and compare them both. Is it possible? Thank you guys.

I tried this:

```
 import os
 from ms_active_directory import ADDomain

 domain = ADDomain(os.environ["domain"])
 session = domain.create_session_as_user(os.environ["userAd"], os.environ["passAd"])
 user = session.find_user_by_sam_name('John Liniker', ["userPassword"])
```

It resulted in: `password = []`

I expected some crypt code as a result.

Comment: For security reasons Active Directory does not allow access to (hashed) passwords in it's database. If you want to authenticate a user using AD/LDAP you need to perform a "bind" (authenticate) the user by sending username and password to the AD. https://blog.thomastoye.be/python-ldap-authentication-with-microsoft-active-directory-46661bebc483